# Stopping CSS inheritance within an element

Tags: css, inheritance, html-email

I can see lots of answers for this but not quite the right solutions..

Essentially i'm displaying numerous emails in a thread (looks like iMessage a bit) on a page.  The messages are looped within a repeated element, with the HTML email displayed inside it.

I have no control over the HTML in the email content as it could be from anywhere..  the problem is that the HTML in the email is inheriting CSS styling from the page style sheets.. this is making it all look weird..

I can't overrule the CSS with a more specific CSS, as there could be any classes or id's coming in the email that match those in the main style sheet..

I've tried adding all:initial to the wrapper div like this:

```
div.sentMsgBody *{
    all: initial !important;
}
```

This however seems to override any styles that comes with the email and so looks really naff..

Anyone got any ideas how to display the email content with its own HTML without taking on the main styles?

Thanks!!

Addition:
I've been asked to show my code, though that's quite tricky...

there's loops of a certain div in the page like this:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="sentMsgBody"></div>
    <div class="sentMsgBody"></div>
    <div class="sentMsgBody"></div>
</div>
```

Of course each loop of this div could have any HTML at all as its showing emails...

eg:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="sentMsgBody">
        <div class="Header">My Email</div>
        <div class="Main">This is my email body</div>
        <div class="Footer">Email Footer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sentMsgBody"> ... ... </div>
    <div class="sentMsgBody"> ... ... </div>
</div>
```

Here the Header and Footer etc may take css from the main page...

I thought about iFrames but they are messy, i don't know how big the content will be for each one, are a bugger with being responsive too, and there could be dozens that have to be created dynamically from the content of each div that is loaded by ajax from a handler.

Comment: show it in an iframe?

Comment: can you please paste your full code? Both HTML and CSS.

Comment: @ZombieChowder  Thanks,  I've added in some details above....

Comment: @Pete - As i've edited above, iframes are tricky and cumbersome so i'd rather avoid it...

Comment: have you tried giving specific classes to each element and embedding the CSS inside the HTML? That way you don't need to include extra files?

Comment: The only thing you would be able to do then is make your general template css more specific so it doesn't mess with any elements in your email

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I was hoping there might be something that stopped it in an easier way..  its part of a huge software so I can't edit the general css without huge ramifications sadly.